# How to get meta tag in a string of html?

Tags: c#, html

I'm truing to get content of  from string with html to a string with c#.

I end up with this, but it didn't work as it should

```
if (source.Contains("description"))
            {
                string St = source;
                int pFrom = St.IndexOf("description") + "description".Length;
                int pTo = St.LastIndexOf(">");


                description = St.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom);
                while (description.Contains(">"))
                {
                    pTo = description.LastIndexOf(">");
                    description = description.Substring(0, pTo);
                }
                description = description.Replace("content=", "");
                description = description.Replace("\"", "");
                description = description.Replace("/", "");
            }
```

Comment: `it didn't work as it should` how it should work? How is it not working?

Comment: It's often gettin wrong text not from tag. I need something like `string title = Regex.Match(source, @"\<title\b[^>]*\>\s*(?<Title>[\s\S]*?)\</title\>",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups["Title"].Value;`